# How to mask 3D Objects with Real-World-Objects in front of them? (Tango, Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

All the Tango Apps and Demos I have seen so far have one major limitation: 3D-Objects are always "on top" of the real world camera image. They are placed correctly in 3D space but a real object in front of the virtual object will not overlap it!

Question:
**Is it possible to mask 3D objects or parts of them in realtime by real world objects in front of them?**

In theory the 3D data deliverd by Tango sensors should be sufficient to do this. But I wonder if anyone has done it before or if there might be performance limitations that make this impossible? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: probably impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use the 3D Reconstruction library (search "Unity How-to Guide: Meshing with Color") to pre-scan the environment, and then use this model to provide depth data when rendering the AR scene.  [Here's a video of an AR game that appears to use this technique.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0cvmJIL1jU&t=33s)  It's not perfect for sure, but it does sorta work.

[This questions has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-project-tango%5D+occlusion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Helped a lot to bring me on the right track: The keyword to search for is "Occlusion with Google Tango". Did not think about that term before.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353080/how-to-do-occlusion-with-google-tango-in-unity